# Can't get into a network drive through Filezilla

Tags: windows, ftp, filezilla, network-drive

On my server, I have a network drive and I want to get access to this drive through Filezilla. The main problem is that every time I'm trying to get there with Filezilla, the client connection is lost with Error 550. I have read a lot about this problem and almost every reply is about making a new windows account but I can't make it. It have to work with other Filezilla clients.

How to make network drive "Visible" in Filezilla client? Please, help!

Comment: Network drive implies Windows File Sharing. Is this about FTP? Or is it about Windows File Sharing? Or are you perhaps trying to access a mapped Network drive on your FTP server via FTP?

Comment: @DanielB : "Windows File Sharing" (more technically called SMB, or even CIFS) is just one kind of network drive.  e.g., if someone asked me whether a specific drive was fixed or used removable media, and that drive used NFS, I may say it is a network drive.  Especially in networks that don't involve Microsoft Windows, the term "network drive" definitely doesn't imply *Windows* File Sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Add new user with share folder as normal on Filezilla FTP server

Step 2 : Modify %filezilla_server_install_folder%\FileZilla Server.xml

example : Permission Dir="D:\"
to Permission Dir="\192.168.11.99\nc"

[image]

Step 3: Create "computer user" on client PC same as "user log on to access file" on \192.168.11.99 with same password

[image]

Step 4 : Open Services on Client PC , find Mozilla Server FTP server, Right Mouse >> Properties >> Log On tab 
Choose Logon As >> This Acount >> Select account user in Step 3, enter password

[image]

Step 5: Stop and Start again this Services

Comment: Wow that's really old school method in 2021

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissions issue. The user/service that the Filezilla server is running on, does not have permission to access the location you are trying to reach.

You'll need to give permissions to the user/service account that is running Filezilla Server, to that network drive.

You will then also need to tell the Filezilla Server that the location is valid for FTP access.